# Get a reference of the different directory paths in my directory stack when using popd, pushd

Tags: bash

I am working on a script for automating a build process at my work. I am using pushd and popd to keep track of, and navigate back to a directory stack. Is there a way to get a reference path to a certain index in the directory stack? For example, I will be navigating up the tree, and pushing the directories to the stack as I move along. Eventually, I want to find a file, and move it to one of the directory paths that is on the stack. I tried doing "mv file.txt popd" at first, but of course all this does is change the name of file.txt.

In short, how do I get a reference to a path that is on my directory stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dirs` command can display the entry at a specified index in the directory stack when invoked as `dirs +N` or `dirs -N`, where `N` is a number. If you want to use it as an argument to a command, you'll need command substitution, e.g. `mv file.txt "$(dirs +2)"`.

Note that by default, for any entry on your directory stack which is within your home directory, `dirs` prints it out using `~` in place of the path to your home directory. But when parsing a command, bash does command substitution *after* tilde expansion, so it will not replace the `~` printed by the `dirs` command with the path to your home directory. To get around this, you need to give the `-l` option to `dirs` to prevent it from printing the home directory as `~` in the first place. (Thanks Justin for noticing this)

You can get the full details of what `dirs` can do by running `help dirs`, or by looking in the man page for bash, about three quarters of the way down.

Comment: When I tried doing it exactly how you had above, just with a different value for the +N, I got this response and nothing seemed to happen `mv: rename timesheet.pdf to ~/Desktop/OFW/ios: No such file or directory`. All I did was add the -l modifier to make it look like `mv file.txt "$(dirs -l +1)"`, it worked just as intended

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't realize it would do that. I'll update my answer for future readers' benefit. Thanks for the feedback!